# who redirection html in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a redirection problem in ASP.NET, I have in the folder view the `_Layout.cshtml` or there is the home page and I created a second page `BookingChamb.cshtml` in the same folder. I have created a link in the submit button on the home page `(<a href="">)` to page `BookingChamb.cshtml`, but the page is not showing and I received this message :

> "Server Error in '/' Application. The resource can not be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure
>   that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /BookingChamb.cshtml "

Thank you in advance

Comment: You are requesting "/BookingChamb.cshtml" but have only booking.cshtml, this can't work :). Either change the booking.cshtml to BookingChamb.cshtml or change BookingChamb.cshtml to booking.cshtml where you are requesting it.

Comment: I changed it but still the same message

Comment: Can you please show us some code from your View, Controller and maybe a screenshot of your folder structure of the solution?Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `asp.net-mvc` you cannot link directly to a view, you need a backing controller action:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult BookingChamb()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And then generate your link with:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Booking","Home","BookingChamb")
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the link code in the _Layout.cshtml page :

```
                                <button class="btn-submit" type="submit"><a href="BookingChamb.cshtml"> chercher</a></button>
```

here is the link code in the HomeController page :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

        return View();
    }
}
```

here is the folder structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zpsZ.png)

Comment: Please update your question, do not provide updates as answers.